# Droidparts Switch ClearableEditText X Clear Button to the left

Tags: android, android-edittext, droidparts

Is is it possible to modify the layout position of the drawable X mark clear button? what was the property to be assign for ClearableEditText to switch the Clear button position to the Left..?

Answer (score 0):

No. Currently it's only on the right.

Comment: @yanchenko thanks from your response.. it would end up in creating my own custom ClearableEditText..